# Design issue in review stats page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, meta, review-stats

On the [review stats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/stats) page, the badge progress is at the bottom of the screen.

[image]

We should fix it.

Same type of issue in [deleted posts page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229820/why-is-there-only-one-close-reason-shown).

Comment: Oh wow, that's bad.